# Consistent URL issue on magento1.9 site optimization

Tags: magento-1.9, image, optimization, pagespeed

Getting issue in Website Optimization:

**Serve resources from a consistent URL** All url are of small image of different products on the same page.

```
https://www.text-machines.com/media/catalog/product/cache/0/small_image/200x/17f82f742ffe127f42dca9de82fb58b1/S/M/SM26120HR_1.jpg
https://www.text-machines.com/media/catalog/product/cache/0/small_image/200x/17f82f742ffe127f42dca9de82fb58b1/S/M/SM26160HR_1.jpg
https://www.text-machines.com/media/catalog/product/cache/0/small_image/200x/17f82f742ffe127f42dca9de82fb58b1/S/M/SM26200HR_1.jpg
https://www.text-machines.com/media/catalog/product/cache/0/small_image/200x/17f82f742ffe127f42dca9de82fb58b1/S/M/SM31120HR_1.jpg
https://www.text-machines.com/media/catalog/product/cache/0/small_image/200x/17f82f742ffe127f42dca9de82fb58b1/S/M/SM31160HR_1.jpg
https://www.text-machines.com/media/catalog/product/cache/0/small_image/200x/17f82f742ffe127f42dca9de82fb58b1/S/M/SM31200HR_1.jpg
https://www.text-machines.com/media/catalog/product/cache/0/small_image/200x/17f82f742ffe127f42dca9de82fb58b1/S/M/SM3180HR_1.jpg
The following resources have identical contents, but are served from different URLs. Serve these resources from a consistent URL to save 5 request(s) and 77.7KiB.

https://www.text-machines.com/media/catalog/product/cache/0/small_image/200x/17f82f742ffe127f42dca9de82fb58b1/S/M/SM18120C_1.jpg
https://www.text-machines.com/media/catalog/product/cache/0/small_image/200x/17f82f742ffe127f42dca9de82fb58b1/S/M/SM1860C_1.jpg
https://www.text-machines.com/media/catalog/product/cache/0/small_image/200x/17f82f742ffe127f42dca9de82fb58b1/S/M/SM1880C_1.jpg
https://www.text-machines.com/media/catalog/product/cache/0/small_image/200x/17f82f742ffe127f42dca9de82fb58b1/S/M/SM21120C_2_1.jpg
https://www.text-machines.com/media/catalog/product/cache/0/small_image/200x/17f82f742ffe127f42dca9de82fb58b1/S/M/SM2160C_1.jpg
https://www.text-machines.com/media/catalog/product/cache/0/small_image/200x/17f82f742ffe127f42dca9de82fb58b1/S/M/SM2180C_1.jpg
The following resources have identical contents, but are served from different URLs. Serve these resources from a consistent URL to save 3 request(s) and 27.7KiB.

https://www.text-machines.com/media/catalog/product/cache/0/small_image/200x/17f82f742ffe127f42dca9de82fb58b1/S/M/SM1840SC_1.jpg
https://www.text-machines.com/media/catalog/product/cache/0/small_image/200x/17f82f742ffe127f42dca9de82fb58b1/S/M/SM1860SC_1.jpg
https://www.text-machines.com/media/catalog/product/cache/0/small_image/200x/17f82f742ffe127f42dca9de82fb58b1/S/M/SM2140SC_1.jpg
https://www.text-machines.com/media/catalog/product/cache/0/small_image/200x/17f82f742ffe127f42dca9de82fb58b1/S/M/SM2160SC_1.jpg
The following resources have identical contents, but are served from different URLs. Serve these resources from a consistent URL to save 3 request(s) and 26.0KiB.

https://www.text-machines.com/media/catalog/product/cache/0/small_image/200x/17f82f742ffe127f42dca9de82fb58b1/g/m/gmc---gml-56120-56180.jpg
https://www.text-machines.com/media/catalog/product/cache/0/small_image/200x/17f82f742ffe127f42dca9de82fb58b1/g/m/gmc---gml-56120-56180_1.jpg
https://www.text-machines.com/media/catalog/product/cache/0/small_image/200x/17f82f742ffe127f42dca9de82fb58b1/g/m/gmc---gml-56120-56180_2.jpg
https://www.text-machines.com/media/catalog/product/cache/0/small_image/200x/17f82f742ffe127f42dca9de82fb58b1/g/m/gmc---gml-56120-56180_2_3.jpg
The following resources have identical contents, but are served from different URLs. Serve these resources from a consistent URL to save 3 request(s) and 15.5KiB.

https://www.text-machines.com/media/catalog/product/cache/0/small_image/200x/17f82f742ffe127f42dca9de82fb58b1/g/m/gmc---gml-4080-40240-hlb6-series.jpg
https://www.text-machines.com/media/catalog/product/cache/0/small_image/200x/17f82f742ffe127f42dca9de82fb58b1/g/m/gmc---gml-4080-40240-hlb6-series_1.jpg
https://www.text-machines.com/media/catalog/product/cache/0/small_image/200x/17f82f742ffe127f42dca9de82fb58b1/g/m/gmc---gml-4080-40240-hlb6-series_1_1.jpg
https://www.text-machines.com/media/catalog/product/cache/0/small_image/200x/17f82f742ffe127f42dca9de82fb58b1/g/m/gmc---gml-4080-40240-hlb6-series_1_1_1.jpg
The following resources have identical contents, but are served from different URLs. Serve these resources from a consistent URL to save 3 request(s) and 14.8KiB.

https://www.text-machines.com/media/catalog/product/cache/0/small_image/200x/17f82f742ffe127f42dca9de82fb58b1/g/m/gmc---gml4080-40120.jpg
https://www.text-machines.com/media/catalog/product/cache/0/small_image/200x/17f82f742ffe127f42dca9de82fb58b1/g/m/gmc---gml4080-40120_1.jpg
https://www.text-machines.com/media/catalog/product/cache/0/small_image/200x/17f82f742ffe127f42dca9de82fb58b1/g/m/gmc---gml4080-40120_1_1.jpg
https://www.text-machines.com/media/catalog/product/cache/0/small_image/200x/17f82f742ffe127f42dca9de82fb58b1/g/m/gmc---gml4080-40120_1_1_1.jpg
The following resources have identical contents, but are served from different URLs. Serve these resources from a consistent URL to save 2 request(s) and 34.2KiB.

https://www.text-machines.com/media/catalog/product/cache/0/small_image/200x/17f82f742ffe127f42dca9de82fb58b1/S/M/SM1440TE_1.jpg
https://www.text-machines.com/media/catalog/product/cache/0/small_image/200x/17f82f742ffe127f42dca9de82fb58b1/S/M/SM1460TE_1.jpg
https://www.text-machines.com/media/catalog/product/cache/0/small_image/200x/17f82f742ffe127f42dca9de82fb58b1/S/M/SM1660TE_1.jpg
The following resources have identical contents, but are served from different URLs. Serve these resources from a consistent URL to save 2 request(s) and 19.9KiB.

https://www.text-machines.com/media/catalog/product/cache/0/small_image/200x/17f82f742ffe127f42dca9de82fb58b1/S/M/SM1460TVS_1.jpg
https://www.text-machines.com/media/catalog/product/cache/0/small_image/200x/17f82f742ffe127f42dca9de82fb58b1/S/M/SM1640TVS_1.jpg
https://www.text-machines.com/media/catalog/product/cache/0/small_image/200x/17f82f742ffe127f42dca9de82fb58b1/S/M/SM1660TVS_1.jpg
The following resources have identical contents, but are served from different URLs. Serve these resources from a consistent URL to save 2 request(s) and 18.3KiB.

https://www.text-machines.com/media/catalog/product/cache/0/small_image/200x/17f82f742ffe127f42dca9de82fb58b1/S/M/SM26120_2.jpg
https://www.text-machines.com/media/catalog/product/cache/0/small_image/200x/17f82f742ffe127f42dca9de82fb58b1/S/M/SM2660_2.jpg
https://www.text-machines.com/media/catalog/product/cache/0/small_image/200x/17f82f742ffe127f42dca9de82fb58b1/S/M/SM2680_2.jpg
The following resources have identical contents, but are served from different URLs. Serve these resources from a consistent URL to save 2 request(s) and 18.3KiB.

https://www.text-machines.com/media/catalog/product/cache/0/small_image/200x/17f82f742ffe127f42dca9de82fb58b1/S/M/SM20120_2.jpg
https://www.text-machines.com/media/catalog/product/cache/0/small_image/200x/17f82f742ffe127f42dca9de82fb58b1/S/M/SM2060_2.jpg
https://www.text-machines.com/media/catalog/product/cache/0/small_image/200x/17f82f742ffe127f42dca9de82fb58b1/S/M/SM2080_2.jpg
The following resources have identical contents, but are served from different URLs. Serve these resources from a consistent URL to save 2 request(s) and 16.3KiB.

https://www.text-machines.com/media/catalog/product/cache/0/small_image/200x/17f82f742ffe127f42dca9de82fb58b1/u/n/untitled-1_3.jpg
https://www.text-machines.com/media/catalog/product/cache/0/small_image/200x/17f82f742ffe127f42dca9de82fb58b1/u/n/untitled-1_3_1.jpg
https://www.text-machines.com/media/catalog/product/cache/0/small_image/200x/17f82f742ffe127f42dca9de82fb58b1/u/n/untitled-1_3_1_1.jpg
The following resources have identical contents, but are served from different URLs. Serve these resources from a consistent URL to save 1 request(s) and 12.6KiB.

https://www.text-machines.com/media/catalog/product/cache/0/small_image/200x/17f82f742ffe127f42dca9de82fb58b1/a/5/a5607_smpl1640_-25.jpg
https://www.text-machines.com/media/catalog/product/cache/0/small_image/200x/17f82f742ffe127f42dca9de82fb58b1/a/5/a5607_smpl1640_-25_1.jpg
The following resources have identical contents, but are served from different URLs. Serve these resources from a consistent URL to save 1 request(s) and 12.2KiB.

https://www.text-machines.com/media/catalog/product/cache/0/small_image/200x/17f82f742ffe127f42dca9de82fb58b1/S/M/SMYCL2060_18_1.jpg
https://www.text-machines.com/media/catalog/product/cache/0/small_image/200x/17f82f742ffe127f42dca9de82fb58b1/S/M/SMYCL2260_1_1.jpg
The following resources have identical contents, but are served from different URLs. Serve these resources from a consistent URL to save 1 request(s) and 10.5KiB.

https://www.text-machines.com/media/catalog/product/cache/0/small_image/200x/17f82f742ffe127f42dca9de82fb58b1/g/m/gmc---gt-3280-32120.jpg
https://www.text-machines.com/media/catalog/product/cache/0/small_image/200x/17f82f742ffe127f42dca9de82fb58b1/g/m/gmc---gt-3280-32120_1.jpg
The following resources have identical contents, but are served from different URLs. Serve these resources from a consistent URL to save 1 request(s) and 9.3KiB.

https://www.text-machines.com/media/catalog/product/cache/0/small_image/200x/17f82f742ffe127f42dca9de82fb58b1/g/m/gmc---gml-1440bgf.jpg
https://www.text-machines.com/media/catalog/product/cache/0/small_image/200x/17f82f742ffe127f42dca9de82fb58b1/g/m/gmc---gml-1440bgf_2.jpg
The following resources have identical contents, but are served from different URLs. Serve these resources from a consistent URL to save 1 request(s) and 8.8KiB.

https://www.text-machines.com/media/catalog/product/cache/0/small_image/200x/17f82f742ffe127f42dca9de82fb58b1/S/M/SM1440_2.jpeg
https://www.text-machines.com/media/catalog/product/cache/0/small_image/200x/17f82f742ffe127f42dca9de82fb58b1/S/M/SM1440_2_2.jpeg
The following resources have identical contents, but are served from different URLs. Serve these resources from a consistent URL to save 1 request(s) and 7.8KiB.

https://www.text-machines.com/media/catalog/product/cache/0/small_image/200x/17f82f742ffe127f42dca9de82fb58b1/s/m/sm26120ach_1.jpg
https://www.text-machines.com/media/catalog/product/cache/0/small_image/200x/17f82f742ffe127f42dca9de82fb58b1/s/m/sm2690ach.jpg
The following resources have identical contents, but are served from different URLs. Serve these resources from a consistent URL to save 1 request(s) and 7.2KiB.

https://www.text-machines.com/media/catalog/product/cache/0/small_image/200x/17f82f742ffe127f42dca9de82fb58b1/2/2/2200g_fel.jpg
https://www.text-machines.com/media/catalog/product/cache/0/small_image/200x/17f82f742ffe127f42dca9de82fb58b1/2/2/2200g_fel_1.jpg
The following resources have identical contents, but are served from different URLs. Serve these resources from a consistent URL to save 1 request(s) and 6.1KiB.

https://www.text-machines.com/media/catalog/product/cache/0/small_image/200x/17f82f742ffe127f42dca9de82fb58b1/S/M/SMSET3280_1.jpg
https://www.text-machines.com/media/catalog/product/cache/0/small_image/200x/17f82f742ffe127f42dca9de82fb58b1/s/m/smset3280.jpg
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to change settings in "search Engine Optimization"?
You find it under Configuration > Catalog > Catalog > There you can choose the Canonical Link for Category and article. Maybe it help also for the images. The canonical tag for the url is a possibility for your problem.

Comment: Hi @Marcel, will It impact my SEO?

Comment: This Point is to optimize SEO. Which settings do you have there? I had this issue with acticles (different options). Sometimes you canot prevent all things that will shows any SEOtools. Which tool give you this "issue" info?

Comment: GTMatrix Shown the issue